# Mobile Safari removing hash and query from URL in address bar

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

I have a problem when I click on the link below (or one similar to it) or type it in manually, it removes everything after the hash on the first load in a new tab. However, when I come out of safari (don't clear cache or close safari) it works.

```
http://test.site.com/#/games/play/cpc_new/index.php
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Same here, did you find a solution?

Comment: Alas, nothing yet. As soon as I have a solution I'll put it up here.